# Why isn't my if statement executing whats inside

Tags: ios, swift

within the `viewdidload()` function I have it run through all the saved longitude and latitude values. It then makes a pin on the map where the pooplocationsLONG and pooplocationsLAT with matching keys are. The problem I'm having is that it stops after printing print `("starting\(i)")`. It goes through all the current keys and they have a value but its not performing whats in the if statement.

It gets all the way to the `print("starting\(i)")` and it prints it with the correct number all the way through. I know it has a value that is not nil because of the output `print(pooplocationsLONG)`. It never gets to `the print("1")`. Am I using the if statement wrong?

```
import UIKit
import CoreLocation
import MapKit

class poopstistics: UIViewController,CLLocationManagerDelegate {
    @IBOutlet var label: UILabel!
    var pooplocationsLONG: [Int: Double] = [0: 0]
    var pooplocationsLAT: [Int: Double] = [0: 0]
    @IBOutlet var map: MKMapView!
    let manager = CLLocationManager()

    func recordLocation() {
        let locValue:CLLocationCoordinate2D = manager.location!.coordinate
        Globalvariables.numofdumps += 1
        print("a")
        let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
        print("b")
        defaults.set(Globalvariables.numofdumps, forKey: "numofdumpskey")
        print("c")
        pooplocationsLONG[Globalvariables.numofdumps] = locValue.longitude
        pooplocationsLAT[Globalvariables.numofdumps] = locValue.latitude
        print("d")
        print(pooplocationsLONG)
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        manager.delegate = self
        manager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
        manager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
        manager.startUpdatingLocation()

        label.text = "Total Dumps: \(Globalvariables.numofdumps)"
        for i in 1...Globalvariables.numofdumps {
            print("starting\(i)")
            if pooplocationsLONG[i] != nil{
                print("1")
                let annotation = MKPointAnnotation()
                print("2")
                annotation.coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(pooplocationsLONG[i]!,pooplocationsLAT[i]!)
                print("3")
                annotation.title = "DUMP \(i)"
                print("4")
                map.addAnnotation(annotation)
                print("5")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It is very unclear what you're asking here. What do you expect to happen? What is the value of `pooplocationsLONG` when `viewDidLoad` is called? What is "the output on line 21?"

Comment: within the viewdidload() function I have it run through all the saved longitude and latitude values. It then makes a pin on the map where the pooplocationsLONG and pooplocationsLAT with matching keys are. The problem I'm having is that it stops after printing print("starting\(i)"). It goes through all the current keys and they have a value but its not performing whats in the if statement.

Comment: It seems clear that they do not have values. If they did, then the `if` statement would execute. Check this with the debugger.

Comment: This is my issue I have it print the value when I call `print(pooplocationsLONG) ` and it does have a value. Is it not able to read it from the viewDidLoad() function?

Comment: Where are you calling `recordLocation()`?

Comment: In seperate swift files I have  poopstistics().recordLocation() being called when a button is pressed

Comment: If you're calling it in a different file your're calling it on a new instance, Your viewDidLoad is using the one local to the current UIViewController.

Comment: whats the best way to fix this? should i make the dictionary a global?

Comment: I wouldn't use a global variable. It might be best pass the data with delegation.

Comment: Thanks I will try this im new to ios programming so this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Your for is wrong. Array in swift init in 0.

```
for i in 0...Globalvariables.numofdumps - 1 {}
```

Comment: why use - 1 after it and I dont want to start from 0 because I dont want that to be used